# How do you say "representative" as in Student Council Representative

Tags: grammar

I"m trying to figure out the best way to translate "representative" as in a "representative in government". In Taiwan people say 班代, but that doesn't seem like it would translate into other student council's where you aren'ts necessarily voted as a class representative, but rather as a rep as a whole.

Thanks!

Comment: 代表 is good, as you wrote in your other question.

Comment: 代表 is appropriate，all 代表，no matter 代表 what，are not necessarily voted.:)

Answer (score 1):

In general,"representative " rather as a rep,but he(or she)is recommended(or be voted) by the people(as you say,by the members of the council). However,sometimes,if the student council is from an organization ,like 'student union','representative 'is the leader or  he is in charge of the organization .

Answer (score 1):

代表 is good enough, no matter in "Student Council Representative" or "representative in government".

班代 is just short for 班代表, which means representative of class.

Answer (score 0):

学生会代表  for Student Council Representative